# Attribute 'SelectQuery' is not a valid attribute of element 'SqlDataSource'

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I work on a project and now i receive an error.
I have a table UserData and I want to connect a database to Registration.aspx page and after i want to see the data from database on a page Manager.aspx

This is the error:

> Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not have a public property named 'SelectQuery'...\Manager.aspx

Code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRegistration" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserData]" 
     SelectQuery="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is a print screen:

http://s30.postimg.org/4goewse5d/Error.jpg

Please help me if someone know what is the problem.

Comment: If you change your SQL command to: SELECT [UserData].* FROM [UserData], does that make it work? I'm not very familiar with this, but quick Googling showed aliasing the asterisk or specifying the table is needed.

Comment: I have 1 SelectCommand already. I cant specify 2 x SelectCommand :(

Comment: That's why I said change and not add :)

Comment: @FlorentinLupascu Change `SelectQuery` to `ConnectionString`

Comment: And first ConnectionString `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>"` ? :(
I cant have 2x ConnectionString...

Comment: What do you want to retrieve from this Attribute? Try to remove it and see if it works.

Comment: @FlorentinLupascu Then remove `SelectQuery`, its not necessary

Comment: I removed SelectQuery and now the error has gone.
But now i have other error...:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example where you can see how to write a `SqlDataSource`

```
  <asp:sqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRegistration"
   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM UserData"   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>"  RunAt="server"> </asp:sqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the entire `SelectQuery` attribute.